# Mavericks 10.9.1 - Copies fail *after* the data has been actually moved

Tags: finder, copy-paste

I'm suddenly having a very strange problem on Mavericks.

When copying large files around my system, between local disks or to and from my NAS server, I randomly get a failure stating "The file ... could not be copied because it is in use."

The problem is that this error message appears *after* the data has actually copied. Suppose I copy a 1GB file. The progress bar moves, network activity occurs (if transferring to the NAS), and so on... The error appears as soon as the file copy should finish.

A reboot does not solve this. This is becoming almost reliably reproducible as well. I have no unusual system extensions installed and this behavior started to appear suddenly and seems to have progressively worsened. Initially when it occurred a second copy often would work, but now a second or even third copy often fails and it takes sometimes upwards of four copies to make it work.

I can successfully copy anything at the terminal using `cp`, but this isn't really a solution - this is such a simple operation and there is no reason it should be causing errors like this.

As i said, the most interesting part is that it is occurring *after* the data has actually been moved. When the copy fails, it then deletes the corresponding destination file.

It's worth pointing out that this does not occur if copying to the *same* drive. For example, hitting <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate a file and make a copy on the same disk never fails. Even moving around the same disk works as it should.

(No, I'm not trying to move, but rather simply copy a file.)

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: This problem has gotten better, but not completely solved. Now, if I back out of the folder I intend to copy to and drop the files onto the *folder*, then copies and moves always succeed. It seems to be a race condition with Quick Look and the file copy process. I've bug reported it to Apple (again) so hopefully they will continue to work this out. At least I have a partially workable, albeit non-elegant, solution.

Answer (score 1):

Mavericks uses SMB2 as default, which still is a little bit buggy and might be causing this problem. You can force Mavericks to use SMB again by entering this in Terminal:

```
echo "[default]" >> ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf; echo "smb_neg=smb1_only" >> ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf
```

and restore SMB2 default by:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf
```

<sup>Source: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20131122083837447</sup>